# If GridSearchCV gives a few estimators with rank 1, which one will it pick as the best estimator?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search, gridsearchcv

Using Scikit-learn's GridSearchCV, if GridSearchCV gives a few estimators with rank 1, which one will it pick as the best estimator `best_estimator_`? Will it pick the first estimator in the list that appears in `cv_results_`?

Unless if I am going blind, I can't seem to find this in the documentation here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it (currently) picks the first one in `cv_results_`.  From [the source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/fd237278e895b42abe8d8d09105cbb82dc2cbba7/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L741), it just takes argmin, which according to [the numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html#numpy.argmin) picks the first index in case of ties.

(It doesn't seem like there's any reason to prefer that, so it seems relatively likely to change.  In particular, implementing a tie-breaker using lowest standard deviation or train score or time or ... seems worthwhile.)

As a quick experiment, use a meaningless (for performance) hyperparameter:

```py
search = GridSearchCV(estimator=LogisticRegression(),
                      param_grid={'verbose': [0, 1, 2]})
search.fit(X, y)
print(search.cv_results_, search.best_params_)
```